# Thunderbird keeps asking for password even if the password is correct

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using thunderbird-11 on ubuntu 12.04. Recently after an update suddenly thunderbird is no longer able to recognize my password and keeps asking for it with the message "login failed - retry". I know my password is correct because my calendar in thunderbird which uses the same password and my webmail is able to take that password. I'm connecting to a 2010 Outlook exchange using imap.

Tried deleting key3.db signons* , removing saved password, reinstalling thunderbird but nothing helped.

Not being ale to send mails is frustrating :-( !!

Comment: Have you tried to to delete and add the mail account to Thunderbird yet?

Comment: No....won't it cause all my existing setup,filters to go away ?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you delete thunderbird, I do believe that the user profiles still remain in your home directory

```
#/home/username/.thunderbird
```

Inside of this directory is going to be a directory structure like this.

> total 16
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 user user  335 2011-09-06 10:24 appreg
>
> drwx------  3 user user 4096 2012-02-21 09:22 Crash Reports
>
> **drwx------ 10 user user 4096 2012-03-14 18:52 ekfsczpd.default**
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 user user   94 2011-09-06 10:24 profiles.ini

The directory listed above in **BOLD** is your user profile. (Assuming you only have 1 email account configured in thunderbird.)

If you do only have one user account, move the profile out of the way.

Be very careful with this command.

```
#mv ekfsczpd.default ekfsczpd.bak
```

This will now force your thunderbird account to essentially recreate itself during the next launch. You will have to re-enter your email address / username /password / SMTP or IMAP account info.

If that fixes the problem then great. Next step is to recover your mailboxes, address list , filters etc...

Close out thunderbird, navigate back to your **/home/user/.thunderbird** directory.

You should now see a new **.default** directory, copy all of your mailbox folders from your old profile to your new profile.

```
#cp -R /home/user/.thunderbird/ekfsczpd.bak/*Mail* /home/user/.thunderbird/newdirectoryname.default
```

This should now copy over your Mail and IMAP mail into your new profile, essentially importing all your mail and message rules.

This should be what you need to situate yourself. You can copy additional config files over for example, the **prefs.js** file, but I wouldn't recommend it.